# Should we split the [storyboard] tag?

Tags: discussion, ambiguous-tags

The [storyboard](/questions/tagged/storyboard) tag (333 questions) is currently used in two sets of questions that have little or no intersection. [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.aspx) and [Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) apparently have classes by that name used to manage animation. At the same time, Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5 introduced a [storyboard concept](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_2.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/00200-SW3) (and a [UIStoryboard class](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) that's used to manage view controllers. Both draw inspiration from the storyboard concept used in movie making, but the uses are otherwise not related -- someone interested in iOS development wouldn't care about questions tagged with 'storyboard' related to WPF.

There are already two questions tagged [uistoryboard](/questions/tagged/uistoryboard), so one possibility is to retag questions with both [storyboard](/questions/tagged/storyboard) and [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) as [uistoryboard](/questions/tagged/uistoryboard). Another possibility would be to create [storyboard-ios](/questions/tagged/storyboard-ios), [storyboard-wpf](/questions/tagged/storyboard-wpf) and [storyboard-silverlight](/questions/tagged/storyboard-silverlight).

Finally, we could leave [storyboard](/questions/tagged/storyboard) alone and use it for all things storyboard-like.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This tag is now at 745 questions and still ambiguous as ever. Can this question get some action?

Answer (score 4):

Using [storyboard](/questions/tagged/storyboard) for questions that are about completely different technologies doesn't make sense: If it possible, I would use the name of the class as tag name; when this is not possible because a class with the same name is used in different frameworks, then I would use a suffix to distinguish for which framework the tag is used.

In this case, I would use [uistoryboard](/questions/tagged/uistoryboard), [storyboard-wpf](/questions/tagged/storyboard-wpf), and [storyboard-silverlight](/questions/tagged/storyboard-silverlight). As pointed out from Kevin Vermeer, [wpf-storyboard](/questions/tagged/wpf-storyboard), and [silverlight-storyboard](/questions/tagged/silverlight-storyboard) are even better, as they would allow users to filter out the questions basing on the framework/technology they are referring to. This schema is already used from other tags, such as [drupal-views](/questions/tagged/drupal-views), [drupal-module](/questions/tagged/drupal-module).

Comment: Why not use [tag:wpf-storyboard] and [tag:silverlight-storyboard], to allow filtering on [tag:wpf-*] [tag:silverlight-*]?  I suspect that far more people will be interested in questions about just [tag:wpf] (4.1k followers) or [tag:silverlight] (2.6k followers) than about [tag:storyboard-*].  As you noted, using [tag:storyboard] for questions about completely different technologies doesn't make sense.

Comment: Oh yes, that is even better.